# How to find owner of sequence in Postgresql 9.6

Tags: sequence, postgresql-9.6

How can I display the owner of sequences in PostgreSQL 9.6 with an SQL query?

Since PostgreSQL version 10 there is a pg_cataglog.pg_sequence table, how was it before?

Comment: In 9.6 they were stored in [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/catalog-pg-class.html) with relkind = 'S'

Comment: Thanks. But then to see the actual owner in `pg_authid` I need special permissions.

Comment: Join to [pg_user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/view-pg-user.html)